# How to add seconds for a cronjob

Tags: linux, debian, cron

This is the current running cronjob :

```
2 1 * * * cd /var/www; php auto.php
```

that says it will be run everyday @ 1:02 AM ... How can i make it to run @ 1:02:05 everyday?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as the cron can only run in minutes interval at minimum.

What you can do to achieve the same effect is to have delay in your script as the fist line:

```
sleep(5); // sleep for 5 seconds
```

This way the script actually starts at `1:02:05`.

Comment: And you could pass the intended delay as an argument to the program.